# “SimulatorTrampoline.xpc” would like to access the microphone

Tags: xcode, microphone, swift5

I recently upgraded to Swift 5, Xcode version 10.2 (10E125), and after fixing a few  compile issues on an app in progress, see this new and never-seen-before request. I can find no evidence of it in my project via direct searching, and no search returns on the net. No return from the pods within the project either.

This concerns me and wondered if anyone has any info on it.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

This is part of Apple's fix for radar 45715977, where Simulator devices would prompt repeatedly to access the microphone (as often as every time your app was run). You can find a brief reference to the fix in the [Xcode 10.2 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/).

There are no references in your project because the prompt comes from part of Xcode itself; it's there so that your apps can use audio services in the Simulator, rather than having to be run on a device. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: In Xcode 11b2, this also comes up for 'access to Documents folder', so knowing where it originated was really helpful.

Comment: I guessed it was Xcode but googled it anyway.  It would be useful if the message said it was from Xcode, e.g. 'Xcode component "SimulatorTrampoline.xpc" would like...'.

Comment: That's scary!  I've just googled this error message having (I thought) never seen it before and found my own comment (above) from about two weeks ago.

Comment: So should I say yes or no?

Comment: It is safe to say yes to this prompt, if you want your apps running in the Simulator to have access to your Mac's audio input.

Comment: In my case, it was asking for access to the desktop. I think it relates to a Mac Catalyst app I'm working on, which is in a folder on my desktop, so told it yes. Hmm...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on what this SimulatorTrampoline.xpc is. Today it asked me for access to files that are managed by OneDrive. I said no. :)

Comment: With Xcode `14.2` I still have this prompt. Thanks for explaining its origin.

Comment: The problem is that after you accept, the dialog keeps reappearing. It refuses to take Yes for an answer.

Comment: When the dialog pops up, consider clicking the ? button at top right and providing feedback to Apple about this message. Maybe a pile of feedback will encourage some kind of improvement, with some kind of option besides "Don't Allow" (and break something?) or "Allow" (and then what happens?).